# slideToggle function as defualt close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [slidedToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to hide and show a div:

`<div id="s">salam</div>`

I want the div, `s`, closed by default. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this -

```
<div id="s" style='display:none;'>salam</div>
```

Comment: I'd rather see that held in a stylesheet, rather than in an inline style, though I assume you're just showing it that way as a quicker example?

Comment: @mori57  that is indeed a quick example.